problems with extracting face pixels from the image
I need to pass the image that comes from the camera through a model with tensorflow, in the _extractFacePixels function the image gets there but the originalImage comes out as null
   // Verificar se os bytes estão disponíveis
   print('entrou no extract');
   if (inputImage.bytes == null) {
     print('primeiro if');
     throw Exception('No image bytes available.');
   }
   
 
   // Converter os bytes da imagem para uma imagem utilizável pela biblioteca `image`
 final img.Image? originalImage = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(inputImage.bytes!));
   if (originalImage == null) {
     print('segundo if');
     //print(inputImage.bytes);
     print('Tamanho dos bytes da imagem: ${inputImage.bytes!.length}');
     throw Exception('Could not decode image.');
   }
 
   // Extrair a região do rosto
   final faceBoundingBox = face.boundingBox;
   final faceRegion = img.copyCrop(
     originalImage,
     faceBoundingBox.left.toInt(),
     faceBoundingBox.top.toInt(),
     faceBoundingBox.width.toInt(),
     faceBoundingBox.height.toInt(),
   );
 
   // Redimensionar para 128x128 pixels
   final resizedFace = img.copyResize(
     faceRegion,
     width: 128,
     height: 128,
   );
 
   // Normalizar os valores dos pixels
   List<double> normalizedPixels = [];
   for (var y = 0; y < resizedFace.height; y++) {
     for (var x = 0; x < resizedFace.width; x++) {
       final pixel = resizedFace.getPixel(x, y);
       final r = img.getRed(pixel) / 255.0;
       final g = img.getGreen(pixel) / 255.0;
       final b = img.getBlue(pixel) / 255.0;
       normalizedPixels.add(r);
       normalizedPixels.add(g);
       normalizedPixels.add(b);
     }
   }
 
   return normalizedPixels;
 } 

How can I resolve this?

If you are taking the camera image from the camera, first you need to convert the CameraImage to img.Image. For android, you can use this function.
image_lib.Image convertYUV420ToImage(CameraImage cameraImage) {
  final width = cameraImage.width;
  final height = cameraImage.height;

  final uvRowStride = cameraImage.planes[1].bytesPerRow;
  final uvPixelStride = cameraImage.planes[1].bytesPerPixel!;

  final yPlane = cameraImage.planes[0].bytes;
  final uPlane = cameraImage.planes[1].bytes;
  final vPlane = cameraImage.planes[2].bytes;

  final image = image_lib.Image(width: width, height: height);

  var uvIndex = 0;

  for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    var pY = y * width;
    var pUV = uvIndex;

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      final yValue = yPlane[pY];
      final uValue = uPlane[pUV];
      final vValue = vPlane[pUV];

      final r = yValue + 1.402 * (vValue - 128);
      final g = yValue - 0.344136 * (uValue - 128) - 0.714136 * (vValue - 128);
      final b = yValue + 1.772 * (uValue - 128);

      image.setPixelRgba(x, y, r.toInt(), g.toInt(), b.toInt(), 255);

      pY++;
      if (x % 2 == 1 && uvPixelStride == 2) {
        pUV += uvPixelStride;
      } else if (x % 2 == 1 && uvPixelStride == 1) {
        pUV++;
      }
    }

    if (y % 2 == 1) {
      uvIndex += uvRowStride;
    }
  }
  return image;
}

Then you can use that img.Image to generate the input array for the model as in your code.

Can I use a conversion like this for inputImage?

If you are using the camera image from the camera package, you need to convert the images like this. If you use images from the image_picker package, it doesn't need any conversion.
